# How to make an app like VEVO?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, customization

The VEVO app on iPhone sets a great sample for video oriented apps. I'm working on something similar, and I want to now how to customize the video controller as VEVO does.

My current app is based on the built-in controller. It's OK, but I want to make it tremendous.

I've attached a screenshot. How to implement the progress bar?

[image: VEVO Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

you can add subviews to `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `view` property such as custom buttons and everything.

Note: if there is something specific about the app you are talking about, i'd suggest posting a screenshot so others can see what you are talking about.

Comment: I've attached a screenshot. How to implement the progress bar? Thanks.